# Does this case constitute plagiarism?

Tags: research-process, computer-science, plagiarism, thesis-committee

I recently read a dissertation where I recognized sentences that appeared in earlier papers but are not cited in the dissertation.
Here are some of [these sentences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JAEE.jpg).
He also appears to be copying from [flashcards](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/76219/who-was-the-first-to-posit-that-culture-determines-the-moral-status-of-things-w) , also without citations.

Does this constitute plagiarism?

Comment: Was it all from the same author?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. The sentences are all in his thesis but none originates with him. He has republished parts of his thesis but that is irrelevant.

Comment: I would say yes. The last example is particularly egregious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the use of unattributed material, or use of quotes without indicating they are quotes even with attribution, is plagiarism.

If it's just a few sentences in a long dissertation, it's plausible that some of it was due to lazy note-taking, like copying the words of others into an intermediate document and not realizing months or years later that they were copied. However, laziness is not really a defense. Maybe a mitigating factor.

Comment: I am not sure if it's due to lazy note-taking. The person who did it has a history of plagiarism. It seems to me that he did his appropration of sentences quite skillfully in his thesis since plagiarism detectors find rather few copied material but a manual sentence by sentence (or parts of a sentence) search reveals that he took a lot of sentences (consecutive 7-9 words) without citation . What is the likely outcome if I report this to the dept chair of the university of his thesis?

Comment: @MSD That depends entirely on the dept chair.